# Excel VBA to select the open the first URL showing in a web page

Tags: vba, excel

I've created the below code with the support from some very supportive people here, now I want the vba to click on the first url showing in the page " mentioned below the web code", then to extract some data from the table will be directed to after clicking on this link.:(   or if I can click on the first image there

"its an intranet url"

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1", Sheets("sheet1").Cells.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
Dim ie As Object

For Each cell In rng

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate ("login URL")
    Do
        If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
            ie.Visible = False
            Exit Do
        Else
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop

    ie.Document.forms(0).all("txtUsername").Value = ""
    ie.Document.forms(0).all("txtPassword").Value = ""
    ie.Document.forms(0).submit
    ie.Visible = True

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "search page URL"
        While .Busy = True Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        For Each Post In ie.Document.getElementsByName("cboFieldName")(0).getElementsByTagName("option")
            If InStr(Post.innerText, "Global Service Reference") > 0 Then Post.Selected = True:

            ie.Document.forms(0).all("txtFieldValue").Value = cell.Value

            ie.Document.forms(0).submit


        Next Post

        DoEvents

    End With


    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))


Next cell


End Sub
```

and below is the web code.

```
<p>
    <font size="3" face="cambria'" color="#e60000">
        <b></b>
    </font>
    <font size="2" face="Tahoma">
        <a href="service/service.asp?id=107210501#items">
            <img src="icons/plus.gif" border="0" align="top" width="19" height="19">
        </a>
        <font size="2" face="Tahoma">
            <a href="service/service.asp?id=107210501">
                <img src="icons/service.gif" border="0" align="top">ASTLX-IPQM-00150
            </a>
            <br>
        </font>
    </font>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If clicking on any image link is your only requirement, you can try like the following.

```
Dim IE as New InternetExplorer, post as Object

Set post = IE.document.querySelector("img[src*='plus.gif']") ''for first image link
'Set post = IE.document.querySelector("img[src*='service.gif']") ''for second image link
post.Click
```

I've commented out the second image link as I was not sure which link you wanna go for.

Alternatively, you can try like this as well:

```
For Each post In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If InStr(post.getElementsByTagName("img")(0).src, "service.gif") > 0 Then post.Click: Exit For
Next post
```

Comment: where should I place the any of the solutions in the code SIM please :) .. 

I've tried to put after the code click on Submit to get the results before the image is showing but I am getting an error

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the website it's a bit difficult to see precisely what you need.
Given your HTML code, it seems you're trying to navigate the relative link `service/service.asp?id=107210501` (which is probably dynamic) - and the way you have to recognize it is by an image with a "service" (at least by the name of the source `icons/service.gif`).

If that's the case, you might try to:

- Get all the `img` elements in the page (`Set allImg = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("img")`)
- Loop through them until when you find the one having source `icons/service.gif` and, once you find it, navigating the link wrapping it. This can be done with:

...

```
link = "www.your-intranet-website.com"
For j = 0 To allImg.Length
    If allImg(j).getAttribute("src") = "icons/service.gif" Then
        link = link & "/" & allImg(j).parentElement.getAttribute("href")
        Exit For     
    End If
Next j
ie.Navigate link
```

I guess a better solution might be provided if you could share at least a screenshot of your website and the full HTML source.